# "Shutting down live logging" displayed numerous times in Xcode console

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm seeing loads of "Shutting down live logging" messages in the Xcode console (or the console app)

Does anybody know where that might be coming from?

In case it was caused by too much verbose logging overloading something, I turning logging down to virtually nothing yet its still being dislplayed.

Anybody any idea where it might be coming from and what it means and whatever is causing it should be rectified?

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The "Shutting down live logging" message typically occurs when you stop debugging or disconnect a device from Xcode. It's a standard indication that Xcode is closing the live logging feature, which continuously displays logs as your app runs.

This message is not indicative of an error or problem that needs fixing. It's just a routine notificatio
n to inform you that live logging is being stopped.

If you're seeing this message frequently during normal development or testing and it's not causing any issues with your workflow, there's generally no need to be concerned. However, if you believe this message is occurring unexpectedly or excessively, it might be worth examining your Xcode settings, debugging configurations, or the specific actions you're taking that trigger this message to see if there's a root cause to address.

Comment: This answer (and many of your other recent answers) looks like it was mostly copy-pasted from ChatGPT or similar. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy